# Android app force close when dismissing progress dialog in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am using a subclass inside my main activity to do an asynctask. I plan to move it into a separate file afterwards I just prefer doing it this way to confirm it is working. I am trying to do a `HTTPRequest` with a progress dialog because of the potentially long waiting times. I am doing nothing in the `doInBackground()` because I've read you cannot access the UI layer from there. Ultimately what is happening is I show my progress dialog on `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`. I am calling each task separately above which could be 99% of my problem but I need to be able to pass my activity to the tasks for them to function properly.

I've broken a lot of the steps down into little pieces. I am getting a null pointer exception which leads me to believe my problem comes from not using execute() but I just can't seem to figure out how that works.

```
new CodeRetrievalItem().onPreExecute(MyActivity.this);

new CodeRetrievalItem().onPostExecute(MyActivity.this);

class CodeRetrievalItem extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

ProgressDialog dialog;
protected void onPreExecute(Activity actpass){
        dialog = new  ProgressDialog(actpass);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Activity actpass){

            // Execute HTTP Request
    try{
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(actpass, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: are you trying to call another activity after dismising your dialof

Comment: you have to **Execute HTTP Request** in **doInBackground** not in **onPostExecute.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `AsyncTask` completely wrong. There are several major mistakes in your code.

**AsyncTask protected methods**

Do not call them yourself. In the [documentation for AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you can find:

> Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.

You have to start your `AsyncTask` by calling `execute(Params...)` method. This will cause that:

1. `onPreExecute()` is called prior to the start of background execution and is called on the main thread
2. `doInBackground(Params...)` is called in background
3. After background execution is finished `onPostExecute(Result)` is called on the main thread.

Unless you call `execute(Params...)` nothing of this will happen.

**Generic parameters**

Moreover there is a problem with your generic parameters. `AsyncTask` has three generic paramters `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` (in your case `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`, you have to match these parameters in the methods' parameters.

Therefore create:

1. `onPreExecute()` instead of `onPreExecute(Activity actpass)`
2. `onPostExecute(Void)` instead of `onPostExecute(Activity actpass)`

Those methods you defined aren't bound to the async execution in any way, they are just some extra methods in the class.

If you need to access the activity inside the `AsyncTask` pass it in different way (e.g. in a constructor). Beware that passing an `Activity` to an `AsyncTask` might lead to possible memory leaks (it's good to utilize `WeakReference<T>` here) and accessing dialogs in `onPostExecute(Result)` might cause crash if not properly handled.

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. Never messed with this before so you helped clear it up quite a bit. Everything is working great now and I'm working with it to implement more features!

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this

```
new CodeRetrievalItem(MyActivity.this).execute();



class CodeRetrievalItem extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
Activity context;
public CodeRetrievalItem(Activity actpass)
{
context=actpass;
}
ProgressDialog dialog;
protected void onPreExecute(Activity actpass){
        dialog = new  ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Activity actpass){

            // Execute HTTP Request
    try{
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```